# How to Traceback C++ in conditions like double free detected or floating point error etc

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, arm, traceback

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <csignal>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "stacktrace.h"

//// TRACEBACK TEST
void trace_handler(int sig) {
    void *array[10];
    size_t size;

    // get void*'s for all entries on the stack
    size = backtrace(array, 10);

    // print out all the frames to stderr


    fprintf(stderr, "Error: signal %d:\n", sig);
    backtrace_symbols_fd(array, size, STDERR_FILENO);

//    print_stacktrace();
    exit(1);
}
int TestTrace1() {

    int a = 8;
    int b = 5;
    int c;
    printf("In Trace 1\n");
    
    // TEST -A ----------
    int * deneme;
    deneme = (int *) malloc(20);
    free(deneme);
    free(deneme);
    
    // TEST -B ----------
//    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
//        c = b / (a - i);
//        printf("Res: %d\n", c);
//    }

    // TEST -C ----------
//    int *foo = (int*)-1; // make a bad pointer
//    printf("%d\n", *foo);       // causes segfault

    return 9;
}

int TestTrace2() {

    TestTrace1();
    return 0;
}

void TraceTest() {
    signal(SIGSEGV, trace_handler);
    signal(SIGTERM, trace_handler);
    signal(SIGFPE, trace_handler);
    signal(SIGABRT, trace_handler);
    signal(SIGBUS, trace_handler);
    signal(SIGSYS, trace_handler);
    signal(SIGPIPE, trace_handler);
    printf("i am in\n");


    int b;
    b = TestTrace2();
    printf("Result is %d\n", b);
}

//// TRACEBACK TEST ENDS

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    TraceTest();
    return 0;
}
```

I can get traceback in **TEST -C** like this (Segmentation fault):

```
i am in
In Trace 1
Error: signal 11:
./test.bin(_Z13trace_handleri+0x20)[0x73200]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x25550)[0xa46dd550]
./test.bin(_Z10TestTrace1v+0x34)[0x73278]
./test.bin(_Z10TestTrace2v+0xc)[0x732a8]
./test.bin(_Z9TraceTestv+0x8c)[0x73340]
./test.bin(main+0x24)[0x73388]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x97)[0xa46cf4e4]
```

However if i try to trace double free error( **TEST -A**) i can catch SIGABTR but cannot traceback the code. Same issue for floating point errors too

```
i am in
In Trace 1
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Error: signal 6:
./mlmfirmwarePlayground.bin(_Z13trace_handleri+0x20)[0x73200]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x25550)[0xa465c550]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x17706)[0xa464e706]
```

If i disable catching signals, execution gives an error like

```
i am in
In Trace 1
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
```

And then quits. This makes me think somehow compiler injects something within code which handles the signalsa like SIGABTR or SIGFPE?

**The Environment is linux and cross compiled arm32**

How can i get a valid traceback?

Comment: The tags matter if you actually want help. And the fact that you compiled C with a C++ compiler makes no difference. Simply put, I see zero C++ here. Therefore the c++ tag is erroneous. I posted the comment as a form of double-check, not to put you on blast. But if you want to get offended, you go right ahead.

Comment: @sweenish your approach is offending. did you ever see before any import like <cstdio> within any c code? Does it makes it CPP if i cover it with a class? The problem is not that. The problem is about error handling. nothing more.